# Retrieve html table contents of TD anchor with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I can not understand how to grab for example href attribute inside table row cell. When I'm trying to do that it seems that second loop does not work for selected `TR` elements

```js
function asd(){
    this.container = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-contents")[0];
    if (!this.container){
        return false;
    }

    this.itemsContainer = 
    this.container.getElementsByClassName("minicart-table")[0];
    this.itemsTable = this.itemsContainer.getElementsByClassName("views-table")[0];
    this.cartDetails = [];

    for (var i = 0, row; row = this.itemsTable.rows[i]; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
            console.log(col[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href"));
        }
        console.log('________________');
    }
}
asd();
```

```html
<div class="cart-contents">
<div class="minicart-table">
    <table class="views-table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="views-field-field-product-image"><a href="url">text</a></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you don't use `jquery`?

Comment: Because you shouldn't have to use an entire library to get an href of an element.

Comment: @Saeed.At please don't.

Comment: don't what? @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: @Saeed.At don't suggest a [*not enough jquery*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335333/1267304) solution.

Comment: @Saeed.At because some projects requires pure JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col` instead `col[0]`

```js
function asd(){
    this.container = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-contents")[0];
    if (!this.container){
        return false;
    }

    this.itemsContainer = 
    this.container.getElementsByClassName("minicart-table")[0];
    this.itemsTable = this.itemsContainer.getElementsByClassName("views-table")[0];
    this.cartDetails = [];

    for (var i = 0, row; row = this.itemsTable.rows[i]; i++) { 
        // only the first column
        col = row.cells[0];
        var anchor = col.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (anchor !== undefined) {
            console.log(anchor.getAttribute("href"));   
        }        
        console.log('________________');
    }
}
asd();
```

```html
<div class="cart-contents">
<div class="minicart-table">
    <table class="views-table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="views-field-field-product-image"><a href="url">text</a></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats pretty clever but second `TD` hold another one anchor - it parses both of them when I only need the first one from `td.views-field-field-product-image`

Comment: ah ok I only was trying fix your error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined` and getting the href value

Comment: I did remove the inner loop for that and only take the first column of each row

Comment: santa will be generous with you this year! keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for that. It is [safe](https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) to use. Example:

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector(".cart-contents a:first-child");

console.log(anchor.getAttribute("href"));
```

```html
<div class="cart-contents">
<div class="minicart-table">
    <table class="views-table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="views-field-field-product-image"><a href="url">text</a></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, here is how to fix your code:

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = this.itemsTable.rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row[i].cells; j++) {
        console.log(col[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

Comment: thats incorrect since the table could have more than 1 `tr` and I need all anchors there. Thats why I'm looping each element.

Comment: @ArnasPecelis if you want to select more elements, just use `document.querySelectorAll(".cart-contents a")` and loop through it. I have updated the answer with a fix for your code though.